# Asp publish website with Sqlite

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

first of all I'm a total newbie with Asp.net. On the other hand I use C# everyday.
So what I have to do is a fairly easy matter except for the fact that I don't know Asp.Net.
I am require to make a simple form that gathers data in a Sqlite database.
I am using VS2008 and the latest version of Sqlite. 
Everything works fine when working locally (I can run the website and add data to the s3db db).

The problems are coming out when it comes to publishing. At the moment I am publishing ON MY FILE SYSTEM accordin to procedure  [Walkthrough: Deploying a Web Site Project by Using the Publish Web Site Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

so when it comes to the paragraph Testing the published Website (published in the folder  C:\CompiledWebSite so the local address is   http://localhost/CompiledSite/Default.aspx)  I get the error:

Server Error in '/CompiledSite' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

which I didn't get when running it from VS2008.

So all what comes to my mind is that it's not a matter of Sqlite format but a problem related to the fact that it doesn't find the .s3db file which in the end there isn't in the folder C:\CompiledSite.
But I added it to the solution! And I can see it in the solution explorer structure. 
I think that all problems come from my being totally unaware of how asp works but I have to find a solution!
can anybody help me?
thanx in advance!

Comment: Have you confirmed that there's a copy of the SQLite DLL that was deployed into the bin directory of the compiled site?

Comment: Are you using x86 or x64 SQLite driver? Are you running in x86 or x64?

Comment: Yes I can see the System.Data.SQLite.dll end NewsLetter.s3db files in my solution explorer panel & in compiledSite directory

Comment: I have a 64bit machine, compiling for AnyCpu and using the X64version of the dll

Comment: Additionaly I noticed now that in the error page I get also the msg:   Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be loaded.



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

 
don't know if it's useful

Answer (score 0):

I found it!!!
from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548421/Anplusattemptpluswasplusmadeplustoplusloadplusaplu

it says to go to IIS and set Application Pools --> Advanced Settings --> Set "Enabled 32-Bit Application" to True and press OK

that worked!!